# run cron on xampp

Tags: cron, xampp

I know how to run a php script via cron of a cpanel of a live website, but I also want to learn how to do this cron thing via xampp on my localhost ?, anyone who can actually tell me the exact steps how to do it ?..my OS is win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cron in xampp. Apache is a webserver. Scripts are called only uppon a reuest by some browser.

So if you like to call a PHP script via web at a special time, you will need a browser accessing this website at that time.

Comment: this is an old question of mine..anyway..thanks for answering..i just ran my scrip on production server ..atleast the cron there is easy to use..